# Unable to print variables in Python when using def function

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a simple neural net. I want to print the initial pattern, weights, activation. I then want it to print the learning process (i.e. every pattern it goes through as it learns). I am as yet unable to do this - it returns the initial and final pattern (whn I put print p in appropriate places), but nothing else. Hints and tips appreciated - I'm a complete newbie to Python!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

p = [ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ] # pattern I want the net to learn
n = 5
alpha = 0.01
activation = []   # unit activations
weights = []      # weights
output = []       # output



def initWeights(n):  # set weights to zero, n is the number of units
    global weights 
    weights = [[[0]*n]*n]   # initialised to zero


def initNetwork(p):  # initialises units to activation
    global activation
    activation = p

def updateNetwork(k): # pick unit at random and update k times
    for l in range(k):
        unit = random.randint(0,n-1)
        activation[unit] = 0
        for i in range(n):
            activation[unit] += output[i] * weights[unit][i]
        output[unit] = 1 if activation[unit] > 0 else -1

def learn(p):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            weights += alpha * p[i] * p[j]
```

Comment: One thing to check is the PEP-8 coding standard for python.  Generally, everyone uses 4 spaces for indentation of python code, along with a number of other conventions:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
Quick summary here
http://wwd.ca/blog/2009/07/09/pep-8-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 7):

You have a problem with the line:

```
weights = [[[0]*n]*n]
```

When you use`*`, you multiply object references. You are using the same n-len array of zeroes every time. This will cause:

```
>>> weights[0][1][0] = 8
>>> weights
[[[8, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0]]]
```

The first item of all the sublists is 8, because they are one and the same list. You stored the same reference multiple times, and so modifying the n-th item on any of them will alter all of them.

Comment: What's the best way to generate a null array then? List comprehensions?

Comment: `[[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: A null list is not the same as a list of null lists. You can use the technique above to generate a single null list, it's multiplying that list where the problem arises. I'd go for list comprehension with xrange.

Comment: Didn't see THC's answer. That's right, only you should use xrange if n is big.

Comment: More generally, using `*` on any mutable object will create the same issue of shared mutability

Answer (score 0):

this the line is where you get :
"IndexError: list index out of range"

```
output[unit] = 1 if activation[unit] > 0 else -1
```

because output = [] , you should do output.append() or ...